# Python 2.7: len() returns wrong value for line from file with newline character

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, newline

I am using WinPython 2.7 on Windows 7 64bit.

I want to open a file, read its contents line by line and when encountering a certain sequence, I want to continue operating on the file contents from there on.

To save the current position, I am appending the length of the current line to a list of line lengths. However, `len(line)` returns a value that is too small by 1. I suspect this is somehow because of Windows' newline character `\r\n`.

Consider the following code for an example.

- testfile.txt:

  ```
   Line1
   Line2
   Line3
  ```
- test.py

  ```
   fn = 'testfile.txt'

   f = open(fn)

   line_offsets = []
   for line in f:
       line_offsets.append(len(line))

   f.seek(line_offsets[1])
   print '%r' % f.read()
  ```
- Output:

  ```
   '\nLine2\nLine3'
  ```
- Expected Output:

  ```
   'Line2\nLine3'
  ```

I tried opening the file by specifying the read method (with universal newlines): `f = open(fn, 'rU')`
but this didn't do the trick either. I can get it to work if I open the file in binary mode, but this is in fact a text file, not a binary file, so I would like to avoid that and I also want to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode, and the `'\r'` won't be stripped from the line. Then the `len` will return the proper byte count.

```
f = open(fn, 'rb')
```

This will be especially important if you port to Python 3, since non-binary files will decode the bytes into Unicode characters as you read them and the count could be *way* off.

Comment: Indeed, in Python 3, you should can only `seek` in text files in fairly limited ways. From the tutorial: `In text files (those opened without a b in the mode string), only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception being seeking to the very file end with seek(0, 2)) and the only valid offset values are those returned from the f.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.`

Comment: Okay, so just using binary mode seems to be the way to go in my case. But why does it not work with 'rU'? Isn't universal newline mode supposed to deal with this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Vertho universal newlines will be explicitly converted to `\n` when read, so if the file contains `\r\n` as two characters your string will only contain `\n` - it doesn't help your problem at all. `seek` always works in a binary mode, even if you open the file in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splitlines()` to get the lines off your file. It has a tolerance for the various newline characters as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the behavior you want here, you can explicitly call `f.tell()` before reading each line, and use `f.readline()` to read the line afterwards. You will likely have to work in binary mode as well due to a [Windows issue with tell()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell), and deal with any line ending issues yourself. Using the file as an iterator will not work as it is buffered and may advance the file pointer beyond the line you are reading in the file.

```
>>> with open('testfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     while True:
...         here = f.tell()
...         line = f.readline()
...         if not line:
...             break
...         print('%02d\t%r' % (here, line))
... 
00  'Line1\n'
06  'Line2\n'
12  'Line3\n'
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `f.readline` doesn't buffer? -- I can easily see this breaking on different python implementations/versions...

Comment: Nope, but it works with CPython 2/3 and PyPy. I would expect other implementations to honor the de facto standard behavior here.